# Android NotificationListenerService gracefully degrade for versions lower than 4.3

Tags: android, manifest, notificationmanager

Is there a way to have the new Android NotificationListenerService gracefully degrade for versions prior to 4.3?

I thought that if the os does not recoginze a service then it is ignored in the manifest. This doesn't seem to be the case here. The following is what is in the manifest.

```
        <service android:name=".services.NotificationListener"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=
                    "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Is there a way to have the new Android NotificationManager service gracefully degrade for versions prior to 4.3?" -- `NotificationManager` has been around since Android 1.0. "This doesn't seem to be the case here" -- please explain **completely and precisely** what your symptoms are.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry I should have mentioned that it is the NotificationListenerService. Basically for android 4.3 and lower, it seems to be crashing the app.

Comment: "it seems to be crashing the app" -- what is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop on this, the problem was that we were using a dependency injection framework that required we plugin our dependencies into generated class files and in the case of `NotificationListener`, this class isn't available for 4.3 and below so that was what was crashing the app.

The solution involved creating a proxy for the `NotificationListener` and plugging the depedencies into the proxy so the app works for pre and post 4.3 android versions :)